# Does Internet Browser affect site speed?

Tags: google-chrome, pagespeed, lighthouse

I'm working on a client site and we pinpointed that their site loads slower on Chrome than other internet browsers:

We have run a pagespeed report on Google PageSpeed through Lighthouse as tried opening the site on different browsers in different locations and different computers

```
Fetch time: Apr 23, 2019, 8:13 AM GMT+2
Device: Emulated Nexus 5X
Network throttling: 150 ms TCP RTT, 1,638.4 Kbps throughput (Simulated)
CPU throttling: 4x slowdown (Simulated)
User agent (host): Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
User agent (network): Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3694.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse
CPU/Memory Power: 664
```

This is the first time we've seen this on a client site, specifically Chrome being slower. Could anyone provide a possible reason why? OR has anyone else seen this before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without code example reproducing the issue it might be difficult for anyone here to help.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if this is the first time you see the output shown above, than take note of `Network throttling` and `CPU throttling`. They are options that simulate a slow network and CPU overload, for a more realistic test environment.

There is ways to disable them, both on the Lighthouse CLI and from DevTools.

And in general, there is always going to be variability on the test results: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/variability.md